# Convert blender shhader to unity/texture

Tags: export

My question is about importing a shader into unity. I know the question was already asked, but for me it doesnt work. Here you can see, what I tried.
[image: original]
this is the original and my aim.
[image]
This is with they combined as you can see.
[image]
And this with the diffuse  bake.
I have no idea why this doesnt work. I also tried to delete the light. But this also doesnt work.
Do you have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You  have to set the light to 100 percent lit, then you get a good looking result. But the second problem i with the black color line  inthe center of the thsirt. Here you  have to bake both materials at the same time,on the same picture. Finally you  get the result as you  want. In my case it looks like:
[image]